# Rails loads Picture only on reload, not if link clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

Since 2 days I'm trying to solve a really strange issue. On first Visit of my rails web app loads a picture, but if you click on Home in the navbar to get to the same page, the picture doesn't load. If you reload the page after this, it appears again.
[For you to see yourself](http://138.68.101.23:3000)
I am totally clueless on how to solve this and whats the cause..

Answer (score 1):

You use turbolinks.

try to put your js-slider code like this

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    // your js-slider code here
  })
});
```

or just put this in `application.js` and require `owl-carousel` from `aplication.js`

Answer (score 0):

try to add below code for home link like:

```
<%= link_to('home', home_path, data: { no_turbolink: false}) %>
```